# Issues using Nautilus on a touchscreen

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus, intel, touchscreen

Nautilus is hard to use on my Dell Venue 11 Pro 7130 vPro laptop's touchscreen, both in Wayland and Xorg desktops.

Tooltip windows pop-up with folder descriptions that block the click on folders or files, and do not go away. On some folders or files, need to click 5-6 times to open the contents. Contextual windows do not remain on the screen, and immediately disappear after I remove my finger from the device screen.

This also occurs on a fresh live DVD system.

[image]
[image]

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

---

```
$ cd /sys/class/drm/; ls
card0       card0-eDP-1     card0-HDMI-A-2  version
card0-DP-1  card0-HDMI-A-1  renderD128
$ cat card0-eDP-1/enabled
enabled
$ cat card0-eDP-1/edid | edid-decode
edid-decode (hex):

00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 4c 83 48 4c 00 00 00 00 
17 17 01 04 85 18 0d 78 0a 3a 75 a2 56 4d 9b 27 
0e 50 54 00 00 00 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 
01 01 01 01 01 01 52 35 80 80 70 38 1f 40 20 20 
23 00 ef 86 00 00 00 1a a8 2a 80 80 70 38 1f 40 
20 20 23 00 ef 86 00 00 00 1a 00 00 00 fe 00 46 
56 30 30 44 80 31 30 38 48 4c 0a 20 00 00 00 00 
00 03 41 15 28 01 00 00 00 0b 01 0a 20 20 00 94 

----------------

EDID version: 1.4
Manufacturer: SDC Model 19528 Serial Number 0
Made in week 23 of 2013
Digital display
Color depth is undefined
DisplayPort interface
Maximum image size: 24 cm x 13 cm
Gamma: 2.20
Supported color formats: RGB 4:4:4, YCrCb 4:4:4
First detailed timing includes the native pixel format and preferred refresh rate
Color Characteristics
  Red:   0.6328, 0.3388
  Green: 0.3027, 0.6074
  Blue:  0.1533, 0.0576
  White: 0.3134, 0.3291
Established Timings I & II: none
Standard Timings: none
Detailed mode: Clock 136.500 MHz, 239 mm x 134 mm
               1920 1952 1984 2048 ( 32  32  64)
               1080 1082 1085 1111 (  2   3  26)
               +hsync -vsync
               VertFreq: 59.991 Hz, HorFreq: 66.650 kHz
Detailed mode: Clock 109.200 MHz, 239 mm x 134 mm
               1920 1952 1984 2048 ( 32  32  64)
               1080 1082 1085 1111 (  2   3  26)
               +hsync -vsync
               VertFreq: 47.993 Hz, HorFreq: 53.320 kHz
Alphanumeric Data String: FV00D
Manufacturer-Specified Display Descriptor (0x00): 00 00 00 03 41 15 28 01 00 00 00 0b 01 0a 20 20  ....A.(.......  
Checksum: 0x94
```

---

Comment: You have an outdated Gnome Shell extension installed. You should try and disable them one-by-one in Gnome Tweak Tool (`sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`), and identify which extension is causing you issues.

Comment: Your OS & release details don't match your pastes. Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS using the GA kernel is 5.4, but 20.04.3 LTS using the HWE kernel uses 5.11 kernel, so something is *missing or wrong* in your details (20.04.2 HWE not-updated uses 5.8; but updated to 20.04.3 with HWE uses the 5.11 kernel)

Comment: I took a screenshot of the extensions and output information about the kernel, corrected the post.

Comment: @mct_ did you disable them all and see if Nautilus recovers? You should log out and log back in after doing so.

Comment: Yes, only the yellow sector of debugging information remained in the log. With the Nautilus, the problem remained. I'll attach a screenshot... Wherever I click on the screen, the black window remains hanging there.

Comment: I also disabled the `onboard keyboard`, but this did not solve the problem. And made a 2GB gif file... the full screen is ~4GB. The screen refresh rate of 119.98 mhz does not solve the problem either.

Comment: After watching your gif, this looks like a GTK+ bug. You have resolved the earlier Gnome shell issue, you can remove that section of your question and focus on the tooltips not dissappearing. Remove all the sections on the errors which have been resolved and the `lshw` and kernel information because they are not relevant, though keep your EDID information in case that might be useful.

Comment: guiverc thanks for the explanation, I tried with GA kernel. I have already installed the build several times.

Comment: I edited the message. Returning the background to the standard position did not solve the problem either.

Comment: The problem with Nautilus manifests itself even in trial mode, during the installation of Ubuntu. I started Ubuntu from a USB drive. So the additional software doesn't matter either.

Comment: @Nate T the question is that I use rEFInd to run the axes and the current kernel 5.11 makes my screen black. Therefore, information about the relevance of the cores was presented here. 
The message has been changed, so his message sounds without context.

Comment: my fault. good to know. I have the same issue sometimes with my DVi screens on 5.11, so I understand completely. Btw a lot of the touchscreen issues in the link have been answered by the devs / community. You might check the responses. May contain what you are looking for.

Comment: @Nate T This is good news, I hope it will be fixed. Yes, I updated 20.04.2 on ..3 and I will get a black screen without grub, it was very sad. I wasn't ready for this.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an known issue with Nautilus. To be precise, it seems like one of a few issues of the kind. [This page](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&label_name%5B%5D=5.%20Touch) documents other users with the same and related issues which have been reported.

You should file a bug report here just to let them know that the bug is still present. Without users like you to report on these issues, they would forever remain issues.

Even if someone else has filed the exact same report, Severity is often calculated by the amount of reports recieved.

Comment: Remember, it is the squeaky wheel that gets the grease..  : )

Comment: Thanks for the information, but my /var/crash/ is empty, I tried to do this several times, but all the logs came to the developer branch in an empty state. I think it would be easier and faster to mail my device than to send the code to the developer.. : )

Comment: As common as touchscreens are on modern PCs and Laptops now, it is certainly a target environment for them, so it is undoubtedly a "bug" in the sense that it deserves a bug report, assuming that everything is up to date on your end. I would do an update/upgrade and retry before sending, but that is all that should ideally be needed. You can try to do as was suggested in the comments w/ GNOME tweak tool, but it should still be reported. Just be descriptive, as you already have here. We are just as much a part of the  process as are the developers. If we don't do our part, they cannot do theirs.

Comment: @mct_ ^^ With open source, there is no R&D funding. All they know is what we tell them.

Comment: Well, of course I understand what you're talking about, but I don't have a tool that I could catch this error and provide the information to the developer. And if I start installing software for developers, I risk becoming a developer myself, which I wouldn't want... honestly. I am a simple user who watches videos and listens to music, uses a file manager that makes mistakes : )

Comment: There is no error. You dont need to provide logs. just tell them what is happening and when. I believe someone else already has [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/951). May or may not be the exact same issue but it is close, no? I would just let them know that the error is still present and maybe give your machine specs. Basically just let them know that the bug is still present, Let them know that you are doing it for their sake (to be helpful) and that of the community if you want.

Comment: Well, I'll think about your words and how it would be better to do this, because past attempts to report this have not been successful. I was at that time on build 20.04.1 or ..2 and sent /var/crash/ files with information about the device. As you can see, build 20.04.3 came with the same problem and with a black screen. But regardless of my further thoughts and actions, I would like to thank you for your kind advice and valuable information. Thanks.

Comment: Shipped: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/951#note_1281432

Answer (score 0):

OK so not quite the answer, but at the end of the day an alternative that gets the job done :-).

I use nemo on my venue 11 7139, it works almost flawlessly with the touchscreen. It does pull in about 20MB of dependencies as it is a "cinnamon" package.
HTH
Steve